# Explain dependencies in package upgrade

Tags: package-management, updates

A part of the manual for update states:

> New versions of currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded
>   without changing the install status of another package will be left at
>   their current version.

Would someone please explain why upgrading one package has anything to do the status of another package? I cannot understand.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have package A installed. There is a newer version of A, however the new version requires package B, which is not currently installed. Then A will not be automatically upgraded, because that would require installing a new package, which is considered a significant enough change that you need to explicitly allow it. (Whether that's a "correct" assumption is debatable.) The same is true if the new version conflicts with a currently installed package, which would then need to be uninstalled.